# Most common way to extend an object

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following object to represent a book:

```
const book = {
    name: undefined,
    author: {
        surname: undefined
    }
}
```

What would be the suggested way to create new instances/objects of the book (aside from using the class approach)? I suppose the ways I've seen it done are as follows:

```js
const book = {
    name: undefined,
    author: {
        surname: undefined
    }
}
let hamlet1 = Object.assign(book, {name: "Hamlet", author: {surname: "Shakespeare"}});
let hamlet2 = {...book, name: "Hamlet", author: {surname: "Shakespeare"}}
let hamlet3 = Object.create(book);
hamlet3.name = "Hamlet";
hamlet3.author.surname = "Shakespeare";
console.log(hamlet1, hamlet2, hamlet3);
```

Is there a suggested way to create instances of a typed object? I suppose the equivalent of having a struct in C and then filling its values after declaration.

Comment: most notably, `Object.assign(book` mutates `book`

Comment: Why not use a function with typed parameters so you can use “new”?

Comment: @Joe could you show an example of how that would be done?

Answer (score 2):

All three behave differently

Take a look at how each individual method effects BOOK

First method ... book and hamlet are the same actual object

```js
const book = {name: undefined, author: {surname: undefined}};
let hamlet = Object.assign(book, {
  name: "Hamlet",
  author: {
    surname: "Shakespeare"
  }
});
console.log('book', book, '\nhamlet', hamlet);
console.log(`book is hamlet`, book === hamlet);
console.log(`book.author is hamlet.author`, book.author === hamlet.author);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important; top:0; }
.as-console-row::after { display:none !important; }
```

Here, book and hemlet share no common objects

```js
const book = {name: undefined, author: {surname: undefined}};
let hamlet = { ...book,
  name: "Hamlet",
  author: {
    surname: "Shakespeare"
  }
};
console.log('book', book, '\nhamlet', hamlet);
console.log(`book is hamlet`, book === hamlet);
console.log(`book.author is hamlet.author`, book.author === hamlet.author);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important; top:0; }
.as-console-row::after { display:none !important; }
```

Here, book.author === hamlet.author - so they too are the same object

```js
const book = {name: undefined, author: {surname: undefined}};
let hamlet = Object.create(book);
hamlet.name = "Hamlet";
hamlet.author.surname = "Shakespeare";
console.log('book', book, '\nhamlet', hamlet);
console.log(`book is hamlet`, book === hamlet);
console.log(`book.author is hamlet.author`, book.author === hamlet.author);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important; top:0; }
.as-console-row::after { display:none !important; }
```

Comment: Apologies if this is a stupid question: I could observe the first method mutates `book`; however, it's not clear to me the difference in the impact of the 2 other methods. To the untrained eye, it looks like `book` remains unaffected in both cases.

Comment: @jsN00b - look at the output of the third snippet closely - hint: `book.author.surname`

Comment: Ah, after the edit - it is clear. shallow copy?

Comment: @Bravo thanks for this. Why does the third example mutate `hamlet.author.surname` but not `hamlet.name` ?

Comment: @David542 - because `book.author` === `hamlet.author` - since `Object.create` creates a *shallow copy* ... book.author is an object, book.name is not

Comment: @jsN00b - indeed